# How do you hook a C++ compiled dll function to a sql database?

Tags: c++, sql, mysql, database, dll

I want to do something like:
lastName SIMILARTO(lastName, 'Schwarseneger', 2)

where lastName is the field in the database, 'Schwarseneger' is the value that lastName field is being compared to and 2 is the maximum number of characters (edit distance) that can differ between the lastName field, and the entered value.

I can implement the SIMILARTO function in C++ using the Levenshtein distance (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance), but how do hook the function in a dll to a mySQL implementation?

Comment: What sort of SQL database? SQL Server? Oracle? Mysql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [MySQL 5.1 Reference Manual :: 22.3.2 Adding a New User-Defined Function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/adding-udf.html)

[This blog post also have detailed instructions](http://rpbouman.blogspot.com/2007/09/creating-mysql-udfs-with-microsoft.html) for building User Defined Function DLLs on Windows.